# Action Bar Sherlock Compatibility

Tags: sdk, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread, forceclose

I was testing my application which has action bar sherlock library on a device that has android version 2.3.6. But it crashes after loading the splash screen. In the manifest I have set the minimum sdk to 4 and the target sdk to 18. The theme is Sherlock.Light. What could be causing the forced closing?

Here is the error log:

```
10-18 12:13:32.874: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.budcode.findaspecialistv1/com.budcode.buddoctorbeta.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No implementations match configuration.
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No implementations match configuration.
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.wrap(ActionBarSherlock.java:224)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.getSherlock(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:31)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.budcode.buddoctorbeta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
10-18 12:13:32.884: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

ABS is 2.1+ only, so you'd need minimum SDK at 7:
`android:minSdkVersion="7"`